# How to import Rotation Forest in jupyter notebook?

Tags: python, python-3.x, jupyter-notebook, classification, random-forest

I want to use rotation forest as a classifier for my problem, so I pip install the rotation forest package..but facing problem using it..to import the package I am using the following

```
from sklearn.ensemble import RotationForest
```

Not sure whether it's the right way of importing it!!

Comment: What problem do you encounter?

Comment: It showed   this..ImportError: cannot import name 'RotationForest'

Comment: Which package did you install? `sklearn.ensemble` does not have `RotationForest`, see here: https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/ensemble.html

Comment: I installed it from here:https://pypi.org/project/rotation-forest/

Comment: That's not part of `sklearn.ensemble`. Does `import rotation_forest` work?

Comment: Yeah..it worked!! Thank you so much@gofvonx

Answer (score 0):

Import from rotation-forest pip package with

```
pip install rotation-forest
```

Later you can call the classifier using

```
from rotation_forest import RotationForestClassifier
```

for classifier, or use tree instead of Forest accordingly.